# Unable to start Android SDK Manager due to SWT invalid starting thread

Tags: android, eclipse, swt

When starting the Android SDK Manager, either via eclipse or via ./android, I get the following error:

```
hamiltont$ android 
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions.
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.createShell(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:168)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.open(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:137)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.open(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:110)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:344)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:322)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:119)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

Searching tells me that I need to supply `-XstartOnFirstThread`, but I don't have any control that I know over this. I've tried removing all of the ".snap" files, removing the entire workspace directory, etc. However, I don't think that's the issue. This is a brand new install of the Android ADT. The original x86_64 swt.jar was only showing a blank white screen, so I downloaded swt.jar from http://www.eclipse.org/swt/, which got me past the white screen but now I get the error above.